# include video in django flatpage

Tags: python, django, django-flatpages

I've never worked with flat pages on Django (or Django at all, for that matter) but am required to create a new flat page and copy video object bits onto the new flat page. The video is in MP4 format, if that makes a difference. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A video needs a player and a location where the video is hosted. So as long as the player is embedded in the html of the page and the video can be found somewhere online, you should have no problem. I have used [Flow Player](http://flowplayer.org/) and Youtube within django that way.